# Winforms datatable(not datagridview) change color of an row based on an a field

Tags: winforms

How can i change color of an DataTable row  based on a field(ex: i wanna change the color of the rows if these have some fields empty) in Windows Forms C# ?

There is something a property for Datatable?

Comment: Is there even such a thing as a datatable UI control?

Comment: Ah sorry, the DataTable is the source of the DataGridView

Comment: I did it, thanks                         dataGridView1.Rows[Rowindex].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.LightBlue;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to hook into the CellFormatting event of the datagridview like shown on MSDN like so :

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, 
    System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    // check against your column name here
    if (dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name.Equals("Balance"))
    {
        // we are now in the correct column
        String stringValue = e.Value as string;
        DataGridViewCell cell = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex];

        switch (stringValue)
        {
            case "high":
                cell.Style.BackColor = Color.Red;
                break;
            case "medium":
               ...
                break;
    }

    }
}
```